# SwiftUI 5: @State property wrapper not required with Observable objects?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the "Managing model data in your app" docs article, section: [Change model data in a view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app#Change-model-data-in-a-view), the following weird phrase grabbed my attention:

"*... With Observation in SwiftUI, a view can support data changes without using property wrappers or bindings ...*"

I have created the following sample view to test this out:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var person: Person = .init(id: UUID(), name: "Stacey")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                person.name = "Sarah"
            } label: {
                Text("change name")
            }
            
            AnotherView()
                .environment(person)
            
            Text("Name: \(person.name)")
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class Person: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

As the docs say, I can read and update the "person" variable without having to add `@State` property wrapper, so what's the point now for using `@State` with `@Observable` objects as the app compiles and works fine in both cases ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I watched the video before, and if I want to change the name in another view, I also don't need to use `@State` property wrapper.

Comment: I missed that you made your Person object into an environment object which makes it globally available in the app so I am not sure if asking about @State is relevant then.

Answer (score 1):

`@State` is a source of truth with storage space in SwiftUI’s secret storage.

An implementation of

```
var person: Person = .init(id: UUID(), name: "Stacey")
```

Can possibly get “reset” when the `View` redraws because the lifecycle is managed by the `View` instead of SwiftUI.

Something similar to the effects of using `@ObservedObject` to initialize `ObservableObject`s.

Apple says in the link you provided.

> By wrapping the book with State, you’re telling SwiftUI to manage the storage of the instance. Each time SwiftUI re-creates BookView, it connects the book variable to the managed instance, providing the view a single source of truth for the model data.

As a side note you also retain the ability to use `Binding` in the `View` that owns the object.

Comment: I also have the ability to use `Binding` using the new `@Bindable` property wrapper (also without having to use `@State` with `person` variable)